# I have installed numpy ,but fail to import it

Tags: keras

I am running the code of paper"Hierarchical Attention Networks for Document Classification" using keras on vscode

when I want to install pandas,it shows:

Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- pandas=0.20.3 -> python[version='2.6.*|3.3.*|3.4.*|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
- pandas=0.20.3 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

according to the above discription,then I decide to create a virtual environment and run the following code

```
conda create -n name_of_my_env python=2.7
conda install Pandas=0.20.3
conda install numpy=1.14.0
```

everything is ok so far.

but a bug appears when running the following code:

```
import numpy
```

it shows "ImportError: No module named numpy"

How I can slove this problem?

Comment: pip freeze show numpy installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's more than one python installed in your computer. Also check which pip did you use when install numpy package (make sure it's a same).

If you are run it on environment variables, check if you're now using the same environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But...I don't how to check if I am using the same environment